# function for dynamically created <a> tag is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i am working on a mobile website with html,js and css.i have created  tag through HTML5 DOM & assigned functions to it. It's not working.

My html code(which i have tried thro' DOM method);

```
    <script>
            var addExhibits = document.getElementById('mycontent');
            function mytest()
            {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'rateMe';
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.id="_1";
    anchor.onclick = rateIt(this);
    anchor.onmouseover=rating(this);
    anchor.onmouseout=off(this);
            div.appendChild(anchor);
            addExhibits.appendChild(div);
            }
   </script>
   <body><div id='mycontent' title="Rate Me..."></body>
```

Code(statically created  tag - works fine)

```
<div id="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
<a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_1" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"></a>
</div>
```

rate(this) is a function in external JS(http://reignwaterdesigns.com/ad/tidbits/rateme/)

Comment: this.id instead of this.

Comment: `this` in your function and `this` on the element are not the `same`. In the function it should be `window` and on the element, it's the `element` itself.

Comment: I'd say you are assigning the result of `rateIt(this)`, instead of the function. Try `anchor.onclick = function() { rateIt(anchor); }`

Answer (score 1):

Your event handler just assign the result of the respective function calls here:

```
anchor.onclick = rateIt(this);
anchor.onmouseover=rating(this);
anchor.onmouseout=off(this);
```

I assume you want them to execute in case of the event instead:

```
var that = this;
anchor.onclick = function(){ rateIt(that); };
anchor.onmouseover = function(){ rating(that); };
anchor.onmouseout= function(){ off(that); };
```

Comment: if he needs only the element it's already passed with "this" or event.target / event.srcElement . your way creates also memory leaks in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call your mytest() function anywhere. That's the first thing I see. The other thing is that you are putting your script above your div (mycontent) so the div has not yet been created when your script is read. But I don't completely understand what your aim is here or what exactly your problem is.

Comment: i used a javascript file from the link i mentioned above. And i'm trying to display 5 stars as image & onclicking the image,it should change.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass this.

you can access your element inside the function in many ways.

```
var addExhibits=document.getElementById('mycontent'),
rateIt=function(e){
 e=e||window.event;
 var target=e.target||e.srcElement;//polyfill for older browser
 console.log(this,target);
},
rating=function(e){
 console.log(this,e.target);
},
off=function(e){
 console.log(this,e.target);
},
mytest=function(){
 var div=document.createElement('div'),
 a=document.createElement('a');
 div.id='rateMe';
 a.id="_1"; // id's shouldn't contain _ - & numbers(1st letter) even if it works.
 a.onclick=rateIt;
 a.onmouseover=rating;
 a.onmouseout=off;
 div.appendChild(a);
 addExhibits.appendChild(div);
};
```

this way you also don't create memory leaks.

ps.: that external js example you using is written very bad.

to make your example work you need to change the strange me/num/sel variables in the external js with the proper one (this/e.target/e.srcElement).